# useEffect triggering Infinite loop in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Why this code makes infinite loop in react. here the useEffect with data and columnDataWithTaskProperty cause the infinite loop but i don't know why

```
const useBoard = () => {
  const { data: columnData } = useGetColumnQuery();
  const { data } = useGetTaskAccordingToStatus();
  const [columnDataWithTaskProperty, setColumnDataWithTaskProperty] = useState(
    []
  );

  const [finalState, sFinalState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const allColumns = columnData?.data?.map((item) => ({
      name: item.name,
      _id: item._id,
      tasks: [],
    }));
    setColumnDataWithTaskProperty(allColumns);
  }, [columnData]);

  useEffect(() => {
      console.log("meeee data deps");
      const updatedColumns = columnDataWithTaskProperty.map((column) => ({
        ...column,
        tasks: data.flat().filter((task) => task.status === column.name),
      }));
      sFinalState(updatedColumns);
  }, [columnDataWithTaskProperty, data]);

  return {
    finalState,
  };
};
```

here is how i'm fetching the data using useGetTaskAccordingToStatus. for fetching data i'm using the react query.

```
const useGetTaskAccordingToStatus = () => {
  const { active_project } = useSelector(projectDataInStore);

  const userQueries = useQueries({
    queries: statesOfTaskManager.map((status) => {
      return {
        queryKey: [status, active_project],
        queryFn: () =>
          customAxiosRequestForGet("/task", {
            status,
            projectName: active_project,
          }),
        onSuccess: ({ data }) => {
          return data;
        },
      };
    }),
  });

  const data = userQueries?.map((item) => item?.data?.data);

  return { data };
};
```

Comment: useGetTaskAccordingToStatus always return new data reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is actually a problem in `useGetTaskAccordingToStatus`. This hook returns a new object each render, therefore triggering the effects each time.

The solution should be to wrap the `map` inside that hook in `useMemo`:

```
const useGetTaskAccordingToStatus = () => {
  const { active_project } = useSelector(projectDataInStore);

  const userQueries = useQueries({
    queries: statesOfTaskManager.map((status) => {
      return {
        queryKey: [status, active_project],
        queryFn: () =>
          customAxiosRequestForGet("/task", {
            status,
            projectName: active_project,
          }),
        onSuccess: ({ data }) => {
          return data;
        },
      };
    }),
  });

  const data = useMemo(()=>userQueries?.map((item) => item?.data?.data), [userQueries]);

  return { data };
};
```

Assuming `useQueries` returns a stable array (only changing it when the query results change), the `useMemo` should fix your problem by only running the `map` when the data actually changes.

Additionally, `useMemo` is actually the correct hook to use in your `useBoard` hook instead of `useEffect`. You want to calculate something based on the state, not synchronize with an external system.

This has the benefit of calculating the values directly when the dependencies change, `useEffect` only runs after render, so the old hook with `useEffect` should actually cause multiple rerenders when the data changes, the `useMemo` variant only one rerender.

```
const useBoard = () => {
  const { data: columnData } = useGetColumnQuery();
  const { data } = useGetTaskAccordingToStatus();


  const columnDataWithTaskProperty = useMemo(() => {
    return columnData?.data?.map((item) => ({
      name: item.name,
      _id: item._id,
      tasks: [],
    }));
  }, [columnData]);

  const finalState = useMemo(() => {
      console.log("meeee data deps");
      return columnDataWithTaskProperty.map((column) => ({
        ...column,
        tasks: data.flat().filter((task) => task.status === column.name),
      }));
  }, [columnDataWithTaskProperty, data]);

  return {
    finalState,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using only one use effect and remove columnDataWithTaskProperty for testing sack, you may return it later on.
here's an example of my suggestion, but can't test it without actual data

```
const useBoard = () => {
  const { data: columnData } = useGetColumnQuery();
  const { data } = useGetTaskAccordingToStatus();
  const [finalState, sFinalState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const allColumns = columnData?.data?.map((item) => ({
      name: item.name,
      _id: item._id,
      tasks: [],
    }));
      console.log("meeee data deps");
      const updatedColumns = allColumns.map((column) => ({
        ...column,
        tasks: data.flat().filter((task) => task.status === column.name),
      }));
      sFinalState(updatedColumns);
  }, [columnData, data]);

  return {
    finalState,
  };
};
```

could you please examine the changes on "check" in this:

```
const useGetTaskAccordingToStatus = () => {
    const { active_project } = useSelector(projectDataInStore);
    const { check, setCheck } = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(check);
    }, [check])

    const userQueries = useQueries({
        queries: statesOfTaskManager.map((status) => {
            setCheck(false);
            return {
                queryKey: [status, active_project],
                queryFn: () =>
                    customAxiosRequestForGet("/task", {
                        status,
                        projectName: active_project,
                    }),
                onSuccess: ({ data }) => {
                    setCheck(true);
                    return data;
                },
            };
        }),
    });

    const data = userQueries?.map((item) => item?.data?.data);

    return { data };
};
```

Comment: this also cause the infinite loop. idk why passing data as a dependency cause the infinite loop

Comment: could you please provide more info about useGetTaskAccordingToStatus ?

Comment: code updated with more info

Comment: it looks fine for me, shouldn't cause infinite loop. does removing "data" from dependencies solve the problem?

Comment: yes it solves the problem byt i need to up to date with data

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this method but I think using an object that is not instantiated as a useState causes this kind of issues when used as a dependency on a useEffect. Using the object as a useState object helps React's useEffect keep track of the changes and prevents those kind of issues.

Try this solution:

```js
// Declare data as a useState object
const [data, setData] = useState({})

// Instantiate data on first render
useEffect(() => {
  useGetTaskAccordingToStatus(setData)
}, [])
```

```js
// Pass setState to function
const useGetTaskAccordingToStatus = (setData) => {
    const { active_project } = useSelector(projectDataInStore);

    const userQueries = useQueries({
        queries: statesOfTaskManager.map((status) => {
            setCheck(false);
            return {
                queryKey: [status, active_project],
                queryFn: () =>
                    customAxiosRequestForGet("/task", {
                        status,
                        projectName: active_project,
                    }),
                onSuccess: ({ data }) => {
                    setCheck(true);
                    return data;
                },
            };
        }),
    });

    setData(userQueries?.map((item) => item?.data?.data));

};
```